# ProgressDialog crash in onPreExecute() method

Tags: android

The ProgressDialog is crashing in onPreExecute() method.

Below is my code snippet:

```
        public class TestCasesActivity extends Activity {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_testcases);

                xmlHelp = new XmlHelper();

                ConfigParser confParser = new ConfigParser();
                confParser.execute();
            }

            private class ConfigParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
                private ProgressDialog dialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(TestCasesActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Loading TestCases Configuration...");
                dialog.show();
            }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            xmlHelp.getNumberOfNodes();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            // Show test cases list here via a ListView
        }
}
```

Please suggest what can be wrong here.
The logcat prints are given below:

> 07-30 08:13:50.511  20200-20200/? E/WindowManager﹕
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.TestCasesActivity
>   has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{31a83555
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:262)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>               at com.TestCasesActivity$ConfigParser.onPreExecute(TestCasesActivity.java:41)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
>               at com.TestCasesActivity.onCreate(TestCasesActivity.java:30)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5984)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2361)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

There is another crash caused by parser before:

```
07-30 08:40:32.651  22982-23154/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.performance_tool, PID: 22982
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Only one root element allowed
            at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl.insertChildAt(DocumentImpl.java:421)
            at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.InnerNodeImpl.appendChild(InnerNodeImpl.java:52)
            at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:306)
            at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:128)
            at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
            at com.XmlHelper.getNumberOfNodes(XmlHelper.java:29)
            at com.TestCasesActivity$ConfigParser.doInBackground(TestCasesActivity.java:46)
            at com.TestCasesActivity$ConfigParser.doInBackground(TestCasesActivity.java:33)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: did it crash during orientation change??

Comment: No, it crashed as soon as the activity was launched

Comment: Please share more details when app is crashing

Comment: It crashes as soon as TestCasesActivity activity is launched

Comment: @webgenius this happens when you are trying to show dialog when the activity is not there. Usually this happens when orientation changes cause your activity is destroyed and re-created

Comment: The orientation neve changed. I am checking in portrait orientation, and I have added portrait orientation in the manifest file too: android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: It is clearly explained in your second error log that, Only one root element allowed. So it means, your xml content having more than one root element. Please check your xml content, otherwise post the xml contnet here,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
You should dismiss the progress dialog at the onPostExecute. Like this.

```
protected void onPostExecute(...){
    // dismiss dialog here
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Have you done this step?

**Solution 2:**
if you done this step on onPostExecute and still you getting the error means please check out the next solution below,

pass your context from onCreate method to AsyncTask like this,

```
confParser.execute(TestCasesActivity.this);
```

And your Async Task will look like this,

```
    private class ConfigParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        Context context;

        public ConfigParser(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading TestCases Configuration...");
            dialog.show();
        }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(...){
       // dismiss dialog here
       dialog.dismiss();
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have updated my question with more code and another fatal error.

Comment: `TestCasesActivity.this` is enough. since its a inner class. No need for solution 2

Comment: @webgenius the new error is due to something wrong while parsing xml. check that

Comment: Yes, problem fixed. Problem was with the XML having multiple root elements. I modified the XML and the problem is fixed now. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

I've done so in my project:

```
class CreaLista extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private IndiceActivity indiceActivity;

        public CreaLista(IndiceActivity indiceActivity) {
            this.indiceActivity = indiceActivity;

            context = indiceActivity;

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }



        private Context context;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Dati in caricamento");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void success) {

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
```